# How to upload CSV file into more than one database table using MySql?

Tags: mysql, csv

I want to upload a .csv file into a database but in 3 different table. I mean like in the .csv file have three columns then I want to insert each column into different table. How can I do it? Can anyone give any example or idea to do this.

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly find how to ask a question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Load your CSV into temporary table then use 3 queries to insert this data into working tables.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example if you wish to upload csv file in `db`

```
public function upload(Request $request){   //upload csv

        $file = $request->file('file');
        $csvData = file_get_contents($file);
        $rows = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csvData));

        //CSV headers
        $header = array_shift($rows);

        $escapedHeader=[];

        //to converting lowercase and remove spaces
        foreach ($header as $key => $value) {
            $lheader=strtolower($value);
            $escapedItem=preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', $lheader);
            array_push($escapedHeader, $escapedItem);
        }

        //storing data to database
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            if (count($header) != count($row)) {
                continue;
            }

            //This will generate a associate array with headers.
            $row = array_combine($escapedHeader, $row);//dd($row);

            // if there are 3 tables named - student, course, grade
            Student::create([
                'fname' => $row['firstname'],
                'lname' => $row['lastname'],
            ]);

            Course::create([
                'course' => $row['course'],
            ]);

            Grade::create([
                'grade' => $row['score'],
            ]);
        }

        Session::flash('message', 'CSV file imported!');

        return response()->json('success');
    }
```

Comment: PHP is excess in CSV importing operation. It must only init it and wait until done. MySQL can do everything itself. No need to drag data through PHP.